# Cypress.io how to check if a webpage contains a specific element, and if it has, start the test

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test which use "for" loop and with every loop it changes the url form the array. Main task is to grab all **img** tags and check if they have an **alt** attribute.

But it happens on some sub pages, that they don't have **img** tags at all. And then my test fails on the current loop, then starts next one.

**AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: img, but never found it.**

I would like to modify my code to check before, if the sub page include some **img**, **and if not**, just to pass the test-case and start another loop.

I tried few times, with "if" statement but I can't handle it on my own...

If someone has some idea, please help :)

Below is a code that check all indexes, also if they dont have **img** inside...

```
describe("#13939 - Accessibility - Alt text and link title - Group", () => {

let url = [
    "https://index-0",
    "https://index-1",
    "https://index-2",
    "https://index-3"
]

for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    it(`Accessibility - Alt text ${i}`, () => {

        cy.visit(url[i]);
        
        cy.get("img").each((item) => {
            cy.wrap(item).should("have.attr", "alt").then((alt) => {
                expect(alt).not.be.empty;
            });
        })
    })
}
```

Thank you for every response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cypress docs explain (and warn about) conditional testing [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-problem).
One possible solution:

```
cy.visit(url[i]);
cy.get('body')
  .then(($body) => {
    let images = $body.find('img');
    if (images.length === 0) {
      cy.log('Nothing here...');
    } else {
      cy.wrap(images).each((item) => {
        cy.wrap(item).should("have.attr", "alt").then((alt) => {
            expect(alt).not.be.empty;
        });
      });
    }
  })
```

Comment: Leonardo, thanks a lot, you helped me 2nd time :) your solution works fine.